# Power series of sum of complex exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis

How do we express $e^z+e^{\alpha z}+e^{\alpha^2z}$ as a power series?
Is it simply

$$\sum \left[\frac{z^n}{n!} + \frac{(\alpha z)^n}{n!}+\frac{(\alpha^2 z)^n}{n!} \right]$$

or is it more complex than this?

Comment: You can simplify it a little.  The three fractions have a common factor of $z^n/n!$, so you can factor that out.

Comment: indeed. thanks , but my point really is that: are the powers correct? does the $\alpha $ simply go beside the $z$ ?

Comment: Yes, that part is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post my comment as an answer so this does not show up in the Unanswered queue:

> Yes.